# Difference between mdf files and server based storage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

For an assignment at my college, we need to know what the difference is between mdf files and server based in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically the same - the point is more how you approach the data:

- in "server-based" storage as you put it, your application is talking to the server and a "logical" database name - the application has **no knowledge** of what file(s) make up that database, and where they are stored - or any of those implementation details - and the  application shouldn't have to know! A DBA can also split up your data into a .MDF file and a whole set of .NDF (secondary data files) files - so just a single .MDF doesn't necessarily make up the entire SQL Server database!
- when using SQL Server **Express**, you can also attach a .MDF file directly - which is in my opinion a bad choice and a messy affair. SQL Server Express will then create a user-instance for you, in the background, and temporarily attach the MDF file to the SQL Server and use it. In this case, your application **must know** the exact location and name of the .MDF file to use - and this "locks down" the database to be just that one single .MDF file - it cannot the split up and optimized by a DBA.